# I want to write an image list to a folder after predicting. How can I solve it?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, prediction

```
predict=[]
for img in glob.glob("test1/*.jpg"):
    n= cv2.imread(img)
    predicted = model.prediction(n)
    predict.append(predicted)
```

How do I save this predicted image list as an images to a folder?
  Model returns 224x224 grayscale pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Use *imwrite* for every image in the list:

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, predicted)
```

This will save the images with name *filename* in the current working directory. If you want to save to another folder, put the path of the file instead of filename:

```
cv2.imwrite(path_to_file, predicted)
```

Comment: It is not worked. I want to save all predicted images to a folder.Thanks.

Comment: Try to add the line right after your _predict.append(predicted)_ (inside the _for_loop)